# Apache Ignite JDBC driver - JDBC Connection Pool options

Tags: jdbc, c3p0, ignite

I'm currently trying to set-up Apache Ignite with C3P0 as my JDBC Connection pool, but I noticed that since the Ignite driver doesn't support transactions, C3P0's not usable.

Has anyone had any luck getting a JDBC connection pool going with the Ignite driver? Suggestions?

---

EDIT:

Updating with exactly why C3P0 doesn't work with Ignite's JDBC Driver

So take a look at [this line of code](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/master/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/NewPooledConnection.java#L120) 
To create a new pooled connection, C3P0 attempts to set transaction isolation through the connection/driver.

That eventually leads us to [this line of code](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/jdbc2/JdbcConnection.java#L360) in the Ignite driver,  which basically tells us that the Ignite driver doesn't support SQL transactions.
Ignite itself DOES support transactions as specified [here](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.2/docs/transactions) but it appears the JDBC implementation does not.

So I need an alternative to C3P0 if I want to set up a JDBC connection pool; any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get any particular exception? Any idea why C3P0 requires transactions? This sounds weird to me.

Comment: are you trying to connect from ignite to some RDBMS, or is the issue that ignite itself presents itself as a JDBC DataSource whose Connections you wish to pool, but those Connections don't support transactions? (i don't know much about ignite, but i know lots bout c3p0.)

Comment: I've updated the question with some more specifics.

Comment: @Steve_Waldman Pretty much correct. Ignite provides a JDBC driver but the connections from that driver don't support transactions. I'm not sure how to get around it in C3P0 either, since there's only one constructor to C3P0's NewPooledConnection

Comment: JDBC mandates that drivers support transactions (or otherwise fake it ;), so it sounds like the Apache Ignite JDBC driver is not compliant with the JDBC specification. Drivers are only allowed to throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` if the API doc explicitly mentions `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` or if the JDBC specification says the method is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the JDBC driver for Apache Ignite isn't currently JDBC compliant. Specifically the part that breaks it is that it doesn't have transaction support.  As a result, your typical JDBC-pool implementation won't work with the Ignite Driver

There's now a ticket for this here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4191

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

ds.setDriverClassName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:ignite:cfg://cache=default@file:///the/path/to/ignite-config.xml");

ds.setInitialSize(2);
ds.setMinIdle(2);
```

Try `BasicDataSource` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html